# CrudKit - Input as Dropdown

Tags: php, crud

I'm using CrudKit v0.3 and I want the user to be able to edit his status, which is an integer representing 9 different strings.

For example:

```
1 = Dog  
2 = Cat  
3 = Cow
```

CrudKit is automatically finding the correct input to use *(In my case, the status is an integer)*. Here's the code I use:

```
->addColumn("status", "Status")
```

In the edit-page it then looks like this:

[image]

My problem is that, I want the user to be able  to select the status from a normal Dropdown list, where a string can represent the integer as I described earlier.
I read through the documentation but I cannot find any way to easily add this, or program it on my own either.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: can you include the code that creates the select element?

Comment: @SergChernata I wish I could, that's what I'm looking for

Comment: I can't help you unless I know what your code looks like. I can give you a general example but how is that useful in this case?